# Why does changing a .Net 8.0 application Target-OS-version from 7 to 10 multiply the output size by 100?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-6.0, .net-8.0

I have a simple WPF application on .Net 8.0. (But I think the following is true for 6.0 as well.)

When leaving the Target-OS-version* at 7.0, the size of the output folder is less than 200 kb.

When changing it to 10.0.19041.0, the result is over 20MB, most of which is a file named Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll .

Why is that needed on 10 but not on 7?

<sub>*Target-OS-version - right-click the project in solution explorer -> click properties -> Target OS version.</sub>

Comment: How simple? Do you have any non-standard references in it? As in, if you make a brand new WPF project targeting .NET 8 does it have the same references that the one you're asking about does?

Comment: My guess is that the huge assembly is just a dependency of apps running on OSv10. Why is it a problem?

Comment: @Logarr I just tested a blank WPF .net 6.0. Try for yourself. Create a WPF app and run it. Then change to 10 and run again. Then check the bin folder and see. One is less than 200kb, the other is over 20MB.

Comment: @tomredfern `a dependency of apps running on OSv10` - apparently so. But why the difference?

Comment: @tomredfern "Why is it a problem" probably because they don't want their users to have to download something 100x bigger?

Comment: Also note the added WinRT.Runtime.dll, gives a good hint at what's going on.  When you target Win10+ then you also get to target the WinRT api.  UWP has not been successful, bit of a secret that Microsoft has been busy deprecating it.  These two dlls became necessary around .net5, the version where they removed the WinRT language projection from the CLR and the framework.  MSBuild is otherwise not smart enough to detect whether you actually use any of these apis, not deploying these dlls ought to be practical.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. `they removed ... from the CLR and the framework.` - Since, presumably, the framework (.Net 5 and above) doesn't include it whether in Windows 7 or 10, that would mean that the CLR in Windows 7 has things which Windows 10's CLR does not. Am I understanding you correctly? (Or are you saying that the CLR can use .Net 4's APIs instead of .Net 5's when running a .Net 5 application?)

Comment: The language projection was added in .net45 and removed again in .net5.  Released concurrently with Win8 on August 2012.  Good riddance btw, that wasn't pretty code and the CLR is better off without it.  UWP certainly was a flawed project, luckily many programmers realized they'd be better off ignoring it.  That it got WPF devs to now ship 20MB files is rather ironic.

Comment: @HansPassant So there's only one CLR which is used by .net45-.net8 (and it's different in win7 from win10) ?  Also, since the default for WPF applications is win7, that would mean that they would fail on win10, which is unlikely, no?

Comment: No, today there's the legacy CLR as used in .net4.x projects and CoreCLR as used in .net5+ projects.

Comment: @HansPassant So my question returns, why would a .net5+ project be different targeting win7 from win10 since presumably the CoreCLR is the same for both? It either includes the 20MB of the **Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll** or it doesn't.

Comment: You misunderstood my explanation, when you target win10 then you *may* use the WinRT api in your code.  That you didn't actually do so is the ironic part.  No such risk for Win7, it doesn't have support for WinRT.

Comment: @HansPassant I indeed misunderstood. Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: I converted Hans Passant's comment into an answer. If it is helpful to you, you could mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

As Hans Passant said:

When you target win10 then you may use the WinRT api in your code. That you didn't actually do so is the ironic part. No such risk for Win7, it doesn't have support for WinRT.

---

Here's why this might result in a substantial size difference:

**Windows Compatibility Pack:**

The Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll is part of the Windows Compatibility Pack, and its purpose is to bridge the gap between .NET and Windows-specific APIs.

When you target Windows 10, the compiler includes the necessary components of the Compatibility Pack to ensure that your application can utilize Windows 10-specific features and APIs.

**APIs and Features:**

Targeting a higher version of the Windows SDK allows your application to take advantage of Windows 10-specific features and APIs.
The Windows Compatibility Pack includes additional functionality that might not be present in the earlier version targeted.
Runtime Dependencies:

Different Windows SDK versions introduce changes in runtime dependencies. When you target a specific version, your application includes the required DLLs and resources to ensure it runs on systems with that SDK version.

To investigate the size difference more thoroughly, you could inspect the contents of the output folder for each build. Look for additional DLLs, resources, or folders that might be present in the output when targeting Windows 10.

**The result of my test:**

As can be seen from the result diagram, there is an additional folder containing the large memory file Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll(10.0.19041.0) in the bin folder.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think this and all .NET runtimes (including desktop app runtime) should be a standard part of Windows updates. It's frustrating that our users have to download packages 10-100x as large as they were under Framework because Windows no longer includes any of this stuff standard.